# Microsoft Access 2010 VB InsertInto syntax error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am totally new to Microsoft Access and VB, what i am trying to do is i have a form with unbounded textboxes which i would like upon clicking a button save the text in each textbox in its unique field.

I managed to write this piece of code with some help from online resources but it keeps giving me syntax error, if someone could point me into the correct way.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO UserInformation(" & _
    "FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTtile, PhoneNumber, Mobile, Email, Fax, " & _
    "IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME, IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME) " & _
  "VALUES('" & Me.qfirstname & "','" & Me.qlastname & "','" & Me.qcompany & "','" & _
    Me.qjob & "','" & Me.qphone & "','" & Me.qmobile & "','" & Me.qemail & "','" & _
    Me.qfax & "','" & Me.qitfirstname & "','" & Me.qitlastname & "');"
```

Comment: You do realize with a bound form, you can still have a save button? Just place the following code behind a button called saved me.dirty = false

Comment: Never NEVER **NEVER** use string concatenation like this to build sql queries. You're setting yourself up to get hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since are `IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME` and `IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME` are invalid identifiers in SQL, you must enclose them in brackets (`[` `]`)

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO UserInformation(" & _
    "FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTtile, PhoneNumber, Mobile, Email, Fax, " & _
    "[IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME], [IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME]) " & _
  "VALUES('" & Me.qfirstname & "','" & Me.qlastname & "','" & Me.qcompany & "','" & _
    Me.qjob & "','" & Me.qphone & "','" & Me.qmobile & "','" & Me.qemail & "','" & _
    Me.qfax & "','" & Me.qitfirstname & "','" & Me.qitlastname & "');"
```

---

**UPDATE**:

I have two nice helper functions for this kind of things.

This one replaces placeholders in a string with values

```
Function Build(ByVal s As String, ParamArray args()) As String
    ' Build("LastName = {0}, FirstName = {1}","Dow","John") --> "LastName = Dow, FirstName = John".
    ' "\n" will be converted to vbCrLf.

    Dim i As Long

    s = Replace(s, "\n", vbCrLf)
    For i = 0 To UBound(args)
        s = Replace(s, "{" & i & "}", Nz(args(i)))
    Next i
    Build = s
End Function
```

This one converts a variant value supposed to contain a text in to a SQL value

```
Public Function SqlStr(ByVal v As Variant) As String
    ' NULL    Returns: NULL
    ' ""      Returns: NULL
    ' "abc"   Returns: 'abc'
    ' "x'y"   Returns: 'x''y'

    Dim s As String

    s = Nz(v)
    If s = "" Then
        SqlStr = "NULL"
    Else
        SqlStr = "'" & Replace(s, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If
End Function
```

You can then use them like this making your code safer and easier to understand.

```
Dim template As String, sql As String

template = "INSERT INTO UserInformation(" & _
  "FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTtile, PhoneNumber, Mobile, Email, Fax, " & _
  "[IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME], [IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME]) " & _
  "VALUES({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9});"
sql = Build(template, _
  SqlStr(Me.qfirstname), SqlStr(Me.qlastname), _
  SqlStr(Me.qjob), SqlStr(Me.qphone), _
  SqlStr(Me.qmobile), SqlStr(Me.qemail), _
  SqlStr(Me.qfax), SqlStr(Me.qitfirstname), _
  SqlStr(Me.qitlastname))
CurrentDb.Execute sql
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is great, enclosing them in brackets works :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you lay out your code like so:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO UserInformation(" _
& "FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTtile, " _
& "PhoneNumber, Mobile, Email, Fax, " _
& "IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME, IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME) " _
& "VALUES('" _
& Me.qfirstname & "','" & Me.qlastname & "','" & Me.qcompany & "','" & Me.qjob _
& "','" & Me.qphone & "','" & Me.qmobile & "','" & Me.qemail & "','" & Me.qfax _
& "','" & Me.qitfirstname & "','" & Me.qitlastname & "');"

CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

It makes it much easier to see mistakes and the sSQL string can be printed to the immediate window for debugging. You will see you have JobTtile.

It is usually better to use an instance of CurrentDB:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDB
```

I wonder why you do not just bind a recordset?

Comment: thats a great way to divide the code, will do so accordingly. Thank You